# fetch POST request is pending (sending data from registration form)

Tags: express, fetch-api

I know that similar questions have already been here, but I didn't find anything for my problem.

1. I am creating project using [Webpack-Express-Pug-VanillaJS] stack of technologies.
2. I'm trying to make POST-request to send formData to '/api/users' using fetch a push data to array in my express file, but its only pending...
   What kind of problems it can be?

## client-side code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 async function postData(url, data) {
  try {
    console.log('addEventListener works!')
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    console.log('fetch works!')
    return await response.json()
  } catch(e) {
    console.warn('Error',e.message)
  }
}

  const forms = document.getElementsByTagName('FORM');
  for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        console.log(forms[i])
          e.preventDefault();
          let formData = new FormData(this);
           formData = Object.fromEntries(formData); 
           console.log(formData) return object like {name:'Zhanna', age:25, email:'123zhanna@gmail.com'}
        postData('/api/users', formData).then(data => console.log('Successful!'))
        })
    }
})
```

## server-side

```
const path = require('path')
const express =require('express')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const users = require('../routes/userInfo')
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware'
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware'
import config from '../../webpack.dev.config.js'
import { v4 } from 'uuid';


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

const app = express(),
            compiler = webpack(config)

app.use(users.router);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.locals.basedir = __dirname;

app.use('/assets',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'assets')))
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
    })
)
 app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))

 


app.get('/registration', (req,res)=> {
    res.status(200).render('registration')
})

app.get('/login', (req,res)=> {
    res.status(200).render('signIn')
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render('index')
    }
)
app.get('/api/users', (req,res)=> {
    res.status(200).json(users.list)
})
app.post('/api/users', (req,res)=> {
    const user = {...req.body, id:v4()}
    users.list.push(user)
    console.log('Data was sent')
    res.status(201).json(user)
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`App listening to ${PORT}....`)
      console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.')
  })
```

*And in my console there is only 3 logs:*

1. addEvent listener works!
2. `<form class="registration--form" id="send-form">...<form>`
   3.`{name: "Zhanna", surname: "Kaymedenova", gender: "female", brth: "07.01.1994", email: "zh.kaymed@gmail.com"}`

Comment: these are only the browser console logs, correct? Do you have server logs aswell?

Comment: @marjay Yes, this is browser logs.  I also have log in server-side (in post request) and it doesn't work!